# Pivot table sum of rows with additional conditions

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I am trying to analyze this pivot table :

[image: pivot table]

I am trying to create a sparsity analysis. Here each '1' represents the date on which the product was sold.

I want to calculate the sum of all 1's for each product from the day it starts selling & divide that sum from the total no. of dates after the 1st day of sale.

Comment: Please provide your dataset as **text**

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can compute the sum using `sum` and the number of days since first sale using a combination of `sum`+`gt`+`sum`:

```
df.sum(axis=1)/df.cumsum(axis=1).gt(0).sum(axis=1)
```

output:

```
>>> np.random.seed(0)
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([0,1], size=(5,5), p=[0.7,0.3])).add_prefix('day_')
>>> df['ratio'] = df.sum(axis=1)/df.cumsum(axis=1).gt(0).sum(axis=1)

   day_0  day_1  day_2  day_3  day_4     ratio
0      0      1      0      0      0  0.250000
1      0      0      1      1      0  0.666667
2      1      0      0      1      0  0.400000
3      0      0      1      1      1  1.000000
4      1      1      0      1      0  0.600000
```

*NB. on a real-life dataset, you have to apply the transform only on the columns containing the dates (i.e., you need to exclude "Products" and "Sales" if they are columns)*

Comment: I did hesitate, don't know if this is more efficient

Comment: It's slightly more efficient, I updated, thanks